# bootstrap dropdown list not working with each looped data

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-bootstrap

**I am working on Angular 8 where I am trying to attach a bootstrap drop-down list with each looped data**

**Code for bootstrap drop-down list**

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

When I am attached with the looped value , button is coming but drop-down is not working

**full html code**

```
<div *ngFor='let data of ApiData'>
  <p> {{data.name}} 

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: before trying it in a loop, did you try once with just one element, if not try that first.

Comment: where are you using dats of "ApiData" ..?

Comment: i think it is because you have it all in a `<p>` tag, try adding the drop down div after the it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)

Try like this:

.ts

```
ApiData = [
  {name :"Test", dropdownItems : ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]}
]
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor='let data of ApiData'>
    <p> {{data.name}} </p>

    <div class="d-inline-block" ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" id="dropdownManual" ngbDropdownAnchor (focus)="myDrop.open()">Dropdown Example</button>
        <ul ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
            <li ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let menu of data.dropdownItems">{{menu}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rxyp9?embed=1&file=app/dropdown-manual.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't loop on the whole Dropdown actually. If you want to show the menu from the Array that you are looping, you need to do this:

```
<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
<a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary  text-light" dropdownToggle> Dropdown Example</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <div *ngFor='let data of ApiData'>
            <li><a href="#">{{data.name}}</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Plus you need to use "let" while looping array in angular.

```
*ngFor='let data of ApiData'
```

Working Demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-dropdown-angular-qutu7m